# Apache Geode - Creating region on DUnit Based Test Server/Remote Server with same code from client

Tags: client-server, remote-server, geode, dunit

I am tryint to reuse the code in following documentation : https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/region_options/dynamic_region_creation.html

The first problem that i met is that

```
Cache cache = CacheFactory.getAnyInstance();
Region<String,RegionAttributes<?,?>> regionAttributesMetadataRegion = createRegionAttributesMetadataRegion(cache);
```

should not be executed in constructor. In case it is , the code is executed in client instance , it is failed on not server error.When this fixed i receive

```
[fatal 2021/02/15 16:38:24.915 EET <ServerConnection on port 40527 Thread 1> tid=81] Serialization filter is rejecting class org.restcomm.cache.geode.CreateRegionFunction
java.lang.Exception: 
at org.apache.geode.internal.ObjectInputStreamFilterWrapper.lambda$createSerializationFilter$0(ObjectInputStreamFilterWrapper.java:233)
```

The problem is that code is getting executed on dunit MemberVM and the required class is actually the part of the package under which the test is getting executed.
So i guess i should somehow register the classes ( or may be jar ) separately to dunit MemberVM. How it can be done?

Another question is: currently the code is checking if the region exists and if not it calls the method. In both cases it also tries to create the clientRegion. The question is whether this is a correct approach?

```
Region<?,?> cache = instance.getRegion(name);
if(cache==null) {
    Execution execution = FunctionService.onServers(instance);
    ArrayList argList = new ArrayList();
    argList.add(name);
    Function function = new CreateRegionFunction();
    execution.setArguments(argList).execute(function).getResult();
}

ClientRegionFactory<Object, Object> cf=this.instance.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY).addCacheListener(new ExtendedCacheListener());
this.cache = cf.create(name);
```

BR
Yulian Oifa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first problem that i met is that
> Cache cache = CacheFactory.getAnyInstance();
> should not be executed in constructor. In case it is , the code is executed in client instance , it is failed on not server error.When this fixed i receive

Once the `Function` is registered on server side, you can execute it by `ID` instead of sending the object across the wire (so you won't need to instantiate the function on the client), in which case you'll also avoid the `Serialization filter` error. As an example, `FunctionService.onServers(instance).execute(CreateRegionFunction.ID)`.

> The problem is that code is getting executed on dunit MemberVM and the required class is actually the part of the package under which the test is getting executed. So i guess i should somehow register the classes ( or may be jar ) separately to dunit MemberVM. How it can be done?

Indeed, for security reasons `Geode` doesn't allow serializing / deserializing arbitrary classes. Internal `Geode` distributed tests use the `MemberVM` and set a special property (`serializable-object-filter`) to circumvent this problem. [Here's](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-cq/src/distributedTest/java/org/apache/geode/cache/query/internal/QueryConfigurationServiceConstraintsDistributedTest.java#L126-L135) an example of how you can achieve that within your own tests.

> Another question is: currently the code is checking if the region exists and if not it calls the method. In both cases it also tries to create the clientRegion. The question is whether this is a correct approach?

If the dynamically created region is used by the client application then yes, you should create it, otherwise you won't be able to use it.

---

As a side note, there's a lot of internal logic implemented by `Geode` when creating a `Region` so I wouldn't advice to dynamically create regions on your own. Instead, it would be advisable to use the [`gfsh create region`](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863) command directly, or look at how it works internally (see [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/CreateRegionCommand.java)) and try to re-use that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
As for region precreation -> the problem is that the code is used for dynamic application, where custom code can use their own cache ( e.g region ).Therefore it would be a problematic to have all the regions precreated , especially on runtime.